# How to get hard disk information from /proc and/or /sys

Tags: linux, hard-disk, proc, sysfs

How can I get hard disk capacity, usage, etc. using the `/proc` or `/sys` filesystems?

If it is possible, please tell me which file(s) I need to process to get that information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Answer

```
   cat /sys/block/sda/size
```

Above file will returns some number like 312581808, then this number need to multiply by **512** standard block size then u ll get long int value in **bytes**, then u can convert to **GB**.

Comment: Is this the usage, availability, or total capacity?

Comment: this is only capacity... question also asks for usage... so presumably not available?

Answer (score 5):

Refer [kernel docs for block device subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/).  [stat.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.txt) is for block device I/O stats.

[Kernel/userspace ABI docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/) is also useful, see [sysfs-block](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-block) for comprehensive list of available sysfs entries.

You can also get block device capacities from `/proc/partitions`.

Comment: from /proc/partitions file difficult to calculate, using /sys/block/sda/size we can get it in single line output.