# How to get disk usage ,availability and total capacity?

Tags: linux

How can I get hard disk capacity, usage, etc. using the /proc or /sys filesystems?

Comment: Please specify exactly what you want: `etc.` makes the question open-ended and almost impossible to answer.

Comment: just the disk usage, available and  total capacity

Comment: Why not simply use `df`?

Comment: my code -> linux command -> file

Comment: my code -> file

Comment: and if the command not installed

Comment: Exact duplicate of  [How to get hard disk information from /proc and/or /sys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/how-to-get-hard-disk-information-from-proc-and-or-sys)

Answer (score -1):

Use `df`; it's in coreutils, so if your Linux system lets you read /proc, it will probably let you execute df.
By the way, not all Linux systems have /proc and /sys.